# Api exposing url with parameters

Tags: c#, angular

I have an API which i'm using for my angular project. 
In my API i'm calling an external API which seems to work fine when I'm on local. But when I'm calling it when it's deployed to Azure it responds with CORS policy. And then expose the url with parameters to the external API.
So my first problem is that it expose the url and the second problem is the cors policy.

**Angular/Typescript**

```
  checkAccount() {
    this.httpClient.post('/api/CheckAccount',
      {
        data
      },
      { headers }).subscribe(
      (data: any) => { 
      },
      () => {
      });
  }
```

**C#**

```
public async Task<string> CheckAccount(Contract contract)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("Base url for external api");
            var resource =
                $"rest of the url with parameters";
            var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);

            var result = client.Execute(request);
            return result.Content;
        }
```

Comment: I believe you will have to allow CORS request on azure app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services

Comment: What do you mean "it expose the URL"? And why is your method marked as async if you're not awaiting anything?

Comment: What "responds with CORS"? The attempt to use the external service, or the attempt to use your on-Azure service?

Comment: @manson it shows the external url in my console. you are right, there is no point in being async

Comment: @CaiusJard From my api to the external api

Comment: Then, the external API is declaring the locations it is willing to serve to, and your API is realizing it isn't in the list. It is the CORS config of the external api that must be updated. Or your C# will have to declare a mode of no-cors and accept any limitations it causes